# Why is this system error showing up?

Tags: python, pygame

**The error reads:**

```
File "FinalProject.py", line 81
    if e.type == QUIT: raise SystemExit, "QUIT"
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**My code for the line looks like:**

```
for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT: raise SystemExit, "QUIT"
```

Comment: The syntax is for 2.x, but it appears you're attempting to run it in 3.x

Comment: `raise SystemExit("QUIT")`?

Comment: @kindall That worked thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to enable an exit button.
You'll need to write this in a different format.
Try this,

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
      pygame.quit()
      sys.exit()
      print 'Ending Program'
```

Comment: All I had to do was add parenthesis. Thanks for the help though!